# Objective-C string arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios

I have a string array as such:

```
NSArray *names;
names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
@"FirstList",
@"SecondList",
@"ThirdList",
  nil];
```

I'm trying to assign an element of this string array to a string variable as such:

```
NSString *fileName = names[0]; // "Incompatible types in initialization"
```

or with casting

```
NSString *fileName = (NSString)names[0]; // "Conversion to non-scalar type requested"
```

I'm trying to do this, so I can use the string in a method that takes a string as an argument, such as:

```
NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:filetName ofType:@"plist"];
```

Is there no way to assign an element of a string array to a string variable?

#### Update from 2014: The code in this post actually would work these days since special syntactic support has been added to the framework and compiler for indexing NSArrays like `names[0]`. But at the time this question was asked, it gave the error mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't use C array notation to access NSArray objects. Use the -objectAtIndex: method for your first example:

```
NSString *fileName = [names objectAtIndex:0];
```

The reason for this is that NSArray is not "part of Objective-C". It's just a class provided by Cocoa much like any that you could write, and doesn't get special syntax privileges.

Comment: Thank you Catfish_Man. What does 'not "part of Objective-C" ' mean, if it is provided by Cocoa?

Comment: Objective-C is a language, like C++ or Java. Cocoa is a library, like .NET or the STL. Cocoa is written in Objective-C, and usable in Objective-C code, but it is not the same thing as Objective-C.

Comment: Also, because Objective-C doesn't provide operator overloading, Cocoa's collection classes can't provide [] support the way STL's std::vector (for example) does.

Answer (score 5):

`NSArray` is a specialized array class unlike C arrays. To reference its contents you send it an `objectAtIndex:` message:

```
NSString *fileName = [names objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you want to perform an explicit cast, you need to cast to an `NSString *` pointer, not an `NSString`:

```
NSString *fileName = (NSString *)[names objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new Objective-C literals is possible to use:

```
NSString *fileName = names[0];
```

So your code could look like this:

```
- (void)test5518658
{

 NSArray *names  = @[
         @"FirstList",
         @"SecondList",
         @"ThirdList"];

 NSString *fileName = names[0];

 XCTAssertEqual(@"FirstList", fileName, @"Names doesn't match ");

}
```

Check [*Object Subscripting*](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#object-subscripting) for more information.